# Between with Explode Variable Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Good Day, I have a problem.

I need to make a query with the result of a price range. I receive a string with these price values, but I need to compare this in the query with a `between`. Here's my code, but it doesn't work.
Thanks for the help.

```
$priceRange = Yii::$app->request->post('priceRange');
            $priceExplode = explode(" ",$priceRange);
            if(!empty($priceRange)) {
               $query = $query->andFilterWhere(['between','dcmCost',$this->$priceExplode[0],$this->$priceExplode[1]]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious error that jumps out here, is that you are setting a local variable and then trying to use an object variable:

```
$priceExplode = explode(" ",$priceRange);
```

Then you utilize, which also has an error:

```
$query = $query->andFilterWhere(['between','dcmCost',$this->$priceExplode[0],$this->$priceExplode[1]]);
```

Note that there is a difference between

```
$object->$var
```

And

```
$object->var
```

You did not make it clear that this code exists inside a class.  If that's the case, then make these changes:

```
$priceRange = Yii::$app->request->post('priceRange');
        $this->priceExplode = explode(" ",$priceRange);
        if(!empty($priceRange)) {
           $query = $query->andFilterWhere(['between','dcmCost',$this->priceExplode[0],$this->priceExplode[1]]);
        }
```